# Install sqlite for php5.6

Tags: php, sqlite

The [php manpage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php) sais, you have to install sqlite via PECL, so I tried the latest version:

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/SQLite-1.0.3.tgz
tar xvzf SQLite-1.0.3.tgz
cd SQLite-1.0.3/
phpize
```

But I cannot install php_sqlite on Ubuntu 15.10 like this. I get an error at `make` :

```
/tmp/SQLite-1.0.3/sqlite.c: In function 'zif_sqlite_open':
/usr/include/php5/main/php_globals.h:32:29: error: 'struct _php_core_globals' has no member named 'safe_mode'
```

And many more, so is there an actual version working on PHP 5.6?

I want to run an old program that uses the function `sqlite_open`

And installing the package didn't make it work:

```
apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

So maybe there's a good wrapper library around that uses [SQLite3::open](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php) to simulate the old functions?

Comment: As of PHP 5.4 sqlite is no longer part of PHP and in only available through PECL.

Answer (score 4):

I've been wracking my brain for a couple of days on this, but this finally worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-sqlite3
```

I have `php5.6` as an executable so I then confirmed that `php5.6 -m` showed `sqlite3` to be loaded and it was.

After that, I was able to execute the following simple script. Previously it was telling me that the class SQLite3 was not found.

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('test.db');
      }
   }

   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the [pecl page](https://pecl.php.net/package/SQLite) shows that package was last updated in 2004. The link you linked also states: "(PHP 5 < 5.4.0, PECL sqlite >= 1.0.0)". Simply said It's not for 5.6.

Regardless you should just install the default package instead of using pecl when this is an option. For ubuntu this is [php5-sqlite](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-sqlite).

The extension you linked is very old. I would recommend taking a look at [SQLite3](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) which should be [included by default.](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php)